# Italic text using PdfWriter and iTextSharp and SetFontAndSize function

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create some pdf files. These documents have several number of pages and on the all of those pages except the last one we need to have a text written in italic font.

Here is my code using PdfTemplate, it works but I couldn't manage to make the string Italic :

```
public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

    template.BeginText();
    template.SetFontAndSize(arial, 11);
    template.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
    template.ShowText("" + (writer.PageNumber - 1));
    template.EndText();

    int index = 0;
    foreach (PdfTemplate temp in templates)
    {
        if ((++index) < (writer.PageNumber-1))
        {
            temp.BeginText();
            temp.SetFontAndSize(arial, 11);
            temp.SetTextRenderingMode(0);
            temp.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            temp.ShowText("- Continued -");
            temp.EndText();
        }
    }
}
```

Would you please help me find a way to make my string appear Italic ?

Answer (score 6):

Bold, italic, regular are all different fonts that happen to have similar names. iText has some shortcuts to transition between them for the built-in fonts (as Md. Nazrul Islam showed) but if you specify your own fonts you need to provide the various weights and styles. For Arial you need to register and use the italic font `ariali.ttf`.

```
//Paths to our font files
var arial_regular_path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "arial.ttf");
var arial_italic_path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ariali.ttf");

//Create base fonts
var arial_regular_base = BaseFont.CreateFont(arial_regular_path, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);
var arial_italic_base = BaseFont.CreateFont(arial_italic_path, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);

//Create sized-fonts using the bases above
var arial_regular = new iTextSharp.text.Font(arial_regular_base, 12);
var arial_italic = new iTextSharp.text.Font(arial_italic_base, 12);

//Test paragraph
var p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Chunk("This is a test using an ", arial_regular));
p.Add(new Chunk("italic", arial_italic));
p.Add(new Chunk(" font", arial_regular));

doc.Add(p);
```

In your sample code you basically want to do:

```
var arial_italic_path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ariali.ttf");
var arial_italic_base = BaseFont.CreateFont(arial_italic_path, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);
temp.SetFontAndSize(arial_italic_base, 11);
```

Comment: If you are using the built in iText paths (which in the OPs case doesn't contain ARIAL), you can can also find _OBLIQUE or _ITALIC suffixes. Ie. BaseFont.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE and BaseFont.TIMES_ITALIC are there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following Code. Just create a ***base font*** and then create a ***font*** and then use it.

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.ITALIC, Color.RED);
```

Comment: temp.SetFontAndSize(arial, 11);
We can only use BaseFont on this line, Font is not a valid argument for this method.